# Looking for a martial arts movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, action, martial-arts

From what I remember about it:

- 1980-2000
- man saves woman from getting robbed at an ATM
- man gets recruited by wrestling/ultimate fighting organization
- man refuses mind-control steroids
- father of saved woman tells man he can date daughter if he can hit him in a fight
- man can not hit saved woman's father
- father of saved woman trains man in martial art
- one of the organization's fighters goes on 'roid rage
- man learns fighting organization is underground gang dealing in drugs, guns, and money
- man learns to move cans and explode watermelons with chi
- man brings down organization

Comment: I have no idea what movie this is, but holy crap does it sound awesome.

Comment: Do you remember if any of the actors were familiar? Was any of them asian? It kinda looks like a Jackie Chan or Steven Seagal movie to me.

Comment: Bunch of beta actors. Main character was blonde/brunette clean cut white guy and rescued woman was asian.

Comment: What was the language?

Comment: @tintinmj English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Superfights (1995) - Movie Poster]

**Superfights** (1995)

*From IMDb*: Jack Cody has always wanted to enter the world of the Superfights, a free fighting tournament. One night, he rescues a girl from a mugging and he becomes a national hero. Then, he is finally given his opportunity to become a Superfighter. He soon discovers a Ninja who tells him that the man behind the Superfights is involved with illegal acts. When this comes to Jack, he must fight now for his life.

Here's another [plot summary](http://www.fistofblist.com/2012_08_01_archive.html) with more details and here's the [trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-hcbZpWNA0).